# Database relation one to one based on type

Tags: database-design

I have the following tables:

- User : Id, TypeId ..
- Type: Id, Name ..

Based on type the user has between 1 to 3 values. For example user 1 is typ B, and type B always has 3 values. Type A always have 2 values. Do I create different value-tables

- ValuesA: Id, Min-value, Max-value, UserId
- ValuesB: Id, Value1, Value2, Value3, UserId
  ...

and use UserId as foreign key, and decide which table I should use based on type. Or do I create one value-table with all value-fields and leave empty fields in some rows, and add ValueId to users table? Or is it a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better way is to [normalize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your value rows.

```
Value
-----
User ID
Type ID
Sequence
Value
```

The primary key to this table is (User ID, Type ID, Sequence).  The Sequence column is what makes the primary key unique.  For Type A, Sequence will be 1 and 2.  For Type B, Sequence will be 1, 2, and 3.

This design allows you the flexibility to have zero values, 5 values, or 150 values for a given user and type.